# Does integration tests itself need to be unit tested as well?

Tags: unit-testing, integration-testing

Note that the question is not asking unit tests of functional code/service VS integration tests of functional code/service. The question is asking: `does integration tests itself need to be unit tested as well?`

For example, we have a `functional code/service A`, and we we have `unit tests B` against those `functional code/service A`, and we also have `integration tests C` against those `functional code/service A` too, do we need to write `unit tests D` against our `integration tests C`?

Comment: What problem do you think that will be solved in this way? Unit tests test something small (class, method, etc).

Comment: Hi Daan, I'm asking, what's your opinion?

Comment: Your example seems incorrect. Your integration test isn't testing an integration. For there to be an integration there needs to be at least two units. Let's say Module A uses Module B. Module A has Unit Test A with Module B mocked. Module B has Unit Test B. Then when you test Module A *and* Module B together that's an integration test. And no, you don't write tests for the tests.

Comment: Thanks for your opinion. BTW, functional code/service A means general a a bunch of  modules instead of just a module.

Comment: @hongchangfirst Your situation seems contradictory. Unit tests check a single unit in isolation from other units. Integration tests check multiple *units* working together. If "functional code/service A" is unit tested it is a unit. If it is integration tested, *what is the other unit it is integrating with*? Could you clarify your question with a more specific example? [Edit it into your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/74045196/edit), please.